# How to change the HTTP header / problems with @fontface in firefox CORS

Tags: html, header

My icon fonts are not properly showing in firefox. Im getting "bad URI or cross-site access not allowed." From what I can find, I need to do what is in the image below. I have read all about how HTTP headers work, but there is a big blank on where I actually implement this. The .htaccess file is something I understand, but the first line, and the Mime types below the .htaccess are a complete mystery. I can see the headers in firebug. Where do I edit these? What am I missing? Everywhere I look it seems implied that I should know what this is - but there is no explanation of this part of the process. Does anyone have the answer?

[image]

My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://sourceofyoga.com"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
```

[image]
.
.
.

The fonts are in the theme folder called source2013. All files are on the same server.

Comment: The "added to .htaccess" part seems to suggest what you need to do to achieve "HTTP Header" part. Had you tried that? Also note that this doesn't seem to be WordPress-specific and is probably better asked at other site in SE network.

Comment: Well, there are wordpress specific ways of adding HTTP headers things in the functions, but Wherever this is best is fine with me. Thanks. And although it may seem to *suggest* something, it is not clear enough for me to understand. I'll put up what my current .htaccess file looks like.

Comment: While WP can and does manipulate headers, it does so for its own pages. Static resources (existing files - images, styles, fonts, etc) are not subject to that processing and are (usually) ignored by WP to be handled by web server settings.

Comment: Are the font files you’re loading hosted on “sourceofyoga.com”? What domain name is the page itself hosted on? (Is it a different domain?)

Comment: Yes. All of the files for this website are hosted on the same domain. I added a picture of the file structure in the WordPress theme incase that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your regular expression in `FilesMatch`.  The example that you cite has its font css files with extension `.font.css`, which is what the regex is looking for.  Based on your current .htaccess file, `ss-social-circle.css` isn't matching the expression and thus isn't getting the header.

Try changing the `<FilesMatch ...>` line to this:

`<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|css)$">`

and see if it starts working.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried that out, and then tried a few different things that your idea made me think of, but nothing working so far. I have the WordPress install in a subfolder - so I was looking in to that, and making sure that any deeper .htaccess files were changed as well - but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend going with whatever they're using at http://html5boilerplate.com, because they're great at staying on top of the latest. Currently, they're using this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://mysite.com"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

This works great for us, FYI.